# Dice simulator for Pig, c++

Tags: c++

I'm actually learning C++ language and I'm doing the Pig Game, which needs a dice to play, my problem is that my dice is always rolling the same numbers , no matter how many times I close CodeBlocks or re-run the program. I would like to say as well, that I already used a variable like: `dice=rand() % 6 + 1`, but I'm currently using:

```
int roll() {
    return rand() % 6 + 1 ;
     }
```

which I consider better(idk why).

Any explanation of why this is giving me the same rolls over and over? Thank you very much for answers ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C style

```
std::srand(std::time(NULL)); // calling it once at the start of program is enough
//later in code
std::rand() % 6 + 1;
```

C++ Style [Source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/)

```
std::default_random_engine generator; // there are many random engines in <random> header
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1,6);
int dice_roll = distribution(generator);  // generates number in the range 1..6 
//For repeated uses, both can be bound together:
auto dice = std::bind ( distribution, generator );
// calling dice() will generate number in the range 1..6 for example int number = dice();
```

Comment: Working fine now! Thank u!

Answer (score 2):

At least in C, before using `rand` you should call `srand(time(NULL));`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness: actually you do not have to call srand() if you like that behavior, also it might be handful for debug.